# difference between passphrase and key file in LUKS

Tags: linux, encryption, disk-encryption, luks

I'm trying to understand with no success the difference between a passphrase and a key file in LUKS. At first I thought they were the same thing, with the difference of a key file being a passphrase provided via a file. It has proven to be false.
Encrypting with

```
cryptsetup --key-file=/path/to/keyfile.txt luksFormat /path/to/drive.img
```

results in a drive that cannot be opened if the text inside keyfile.txt is used in the passphrase prompt just after

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /path/to/drive.img devicename
```

The man page of `cryptsetup` says:

> With LUKS, passphrases supplied via --key-file are always the existing
> passphrases requested by a command, except in the case of *luksFormat*
> where --key-file is equivalent to the positional key file argument.

which makes no sense to me.

I have additional few questions:

1. Is encrypting with a key file in general more secure than using a passphrase, since a passphrase' length is limited to what someone is willing to type?
   If that is true:
2. what is the use of adding key files to keyslots at a later time since they do not add security, which is bounded by the weaker passphrase?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to both additional questions would seem to be - A key file and passphrase provide different benefits - A key file is harder to force/crack/deduce then a passphrase  however it suffers a weakness that it needs to be stored on disk/usage cases - so if the computer is stolen with the key file device it doesnt provide protection.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with my passphrase and key file while testing LUKS.  I thought that putting the passphrase into the file would allow me to use a single key slot with either.

Turns out that my key file was not exactly like my passphrase.  In short on the command line, the passphrase stops at the new line.  In a key file, the entire file is read, including newlines.  Further detail can be found in the cryptsetup man page section on processing passphrases.

My error was that the key file had a newline (\n) at the end which made it different from the command line passphrase.  Recreating my test key with

```
# the -n suppresses the trailing newline
echo -n abcd12345 > keyfile
```

resolved the differences and allowed both the key file and passphrase to work with a single key slot.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of PKI, the passphrase is the key used for symmetric encryption of the private key. You can relatively securely store encrypted private keys on a disk\removable (if your passphrase is hard to brute force). There are also applications like ssh-agent or gpg-agent which asks for the passphrase once and store the key in unencrypted form in memory for reuse. If the media is stolen along with the private key, it will be useless.